# Get last 2 updated unit_price from price changing table in last month

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table which records all the price changes on the items on each cost_price, **unit_price** and special_price. The table records the data even if one of the pricing is changed from the old one. The table structure sample is given below.

```
 id | item_id | cost_price  | unit_price   | special_price | created_date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 |   101   |    100      |  NULL        |   NULL        | 2018-07-15 10:02:20
  2 |   102   |   NULL      |  250         |   NULL        | 2018-07-16 12:23:00
  3 |   101   |   NULL      |  150         |   NULL        | 2018-07-16 10:02:20
  4 |   101   |   NULL      |  200         |   NULL        | 2018-07-18 12:23:00
  5 |   101   |   NULL      |  201         |   NULL        | 2018-07-22 10:02:20
  6 |   102   |   NULL      |  283         |   NULL        | 2018-07-28 12:23:00
```

I want to get the following output from the above table (for date from 13-07-2018) for the last month

```
item_id   |   unit_price   | changed_date
-----------------------------------------
   101    |    201         | 2018-07-22 10:02:20
   101    |    200         | 2018-07-18 12:23:00
   102    |    283         | 2018-07-28 12:23:00
```

I need the above output where its only shows the last two changes happen in the **unit_price**.

Comment: Mysql version ?

Comment: What part of the problem does this fail to address: `select * from my_table order by changed_date desc limit 3`?

Comment: @skelwa mysql version  5.6

Comment: @Strawberry Query needs to get only the last 2 distinct unit_price changes within the last month.

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: In this table, the primary key is id.

Comment: Then how come '4' is repeated !?!?!?!?! See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sorry my fault, its suppose to be 6. Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

This might seem complex:

```
SELECT t1.item_id,t1.unit_price,t1.created_date AS changed_date
FROM table_name t1 INNER JOIN 
   (
    SELECT a.item_id, a.unit_price, MAX(a.created_date) AS changed_date
    FROM table_name a INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT item_id, unit_price, MAX(created_date) AS changed_date
    FROM table_name GROUP BY item_id, unit_price) b
    ON a.item_id =  b.item_id and a.created_date < b.changed_date
    GROUP BY a.item_id, a.unit_price
   ) t2
   ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id AND t1.created_date >= t2.changed_date
```

Answer (score 0):

For each item, you want up to the last two changes.  In MySQL (prior to V8) you can use variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@i = item_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@i := item_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select t.*
            from t
            order by t.item_id, t.changed_date desc
           ) t cross join
           (select @i := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) t
where rn <= 2;
```

Comment: The problem I have is, i want to get only the last two unit_price  changes on each items. In the table data, there are NULL values for unit_price when cost_price or special_price is changed.